# android URLConnection.getInputStream protocol exception

Tags: android

i'm trying to download an audio file from a url, here is the code

```
try { 

            URL url = new URL(urll);
            File extStore = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(extStore, "disk.wav");

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download begining");
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download url:" + url);
            Log.d("ImageManager", "downloaded file name:" + "disk.wav");
             URLConnection ucon =  url.openConnection();
            ((HttpURLConnection) ucon).setRequestMethod("GET");
            ucon.setDoInput(false);
            ucon.connect();
            InputStream is =  ucon.getInputStream();
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

            ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
            int current = 0;
            while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
                baf.append((byte) current);
            }

            /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
            fos.close();
            Log.d("ImageManager", "download ready in" + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000) + " sec");

            mediaPlayer.reset();
            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/disk.wav");
            mediaPlayer.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

when it reaches this line :

```
InputStream is =  ucon.getInputStream();
```

it throws :

```
java.net.ProtocolException: This protocol does not support input
```

i have tried with HttpURLConnection but no luck
any one has a clue about what is happening
thanks all

Comment: you are setting do input to false `ucon.setDoInput(false);` and then trying to read the inutstream.. please set it to true `ucon.setDoInput(true);`. if that still does not work, what kind of URL are you using..?

Comment: when it is set to true; i get FileNotFoundException at 
URLConnection ucon =  url.openConnection();

Comment: can you share the URL you are using? can you try the URL on browser to check if it is working?

Comment: unfortunatly i can't share the url, it works on VLC, and on the browser i can read it with VLC plugin and also i can download a WAV file

Comment: is it a RTSP/RTP URL?

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this:

```
URL myUrl = new URL(/*Your Url String*/);
HttpUrlConnection mCon = (HttpUrlConnection)mCon.openConnection();
InputStream in = mCon.connect();
```

Comment: i don't believe you can do InputStream in = mCon.connect();  mCon.connect() returns void

Comment: You can.. mCon.setDoInput(true);

Comment: My mistake... do con.getInputStream();

Comment: when setDoInput is set to true; i get FileNotFoundException at URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection(); please see the comments above

Comment: Abhishek only use setDoInput(true) when you are calling by Post.